# Batch missing operator script fails

Tags: variables, batch-file, math

First off, I read everybody else's questions that were similar, but none of the given solutions worked.  This is also one of my first batch files.  The idea behind it is that I press [D] to move the block X to the right, and [A] to move it left.  Here is the script.

```
@echo off
:start
set z=%q%
if "%z%"=="" set z=5
choice /c ad
set x=%errorlevel%
if %x%==a goto a
if %x%==d goto b
:sett
set /a q="%z% %y% 1"
if %q%==1 goto 1
if %q%==2 goto 2
if %q%==3 goto 3
if %q%==4 goto 4
if %q%==5 goto 5
if %q%==6 goto 6
if %q%==7 goto 7
if %q%==8 goto 8
if %q%==9 goto 9
if %q%==10 set q=1 && goto 1
pause
:a
set y="-"
goto sett
:b
set y="+"
goto sett
:1
echo.X
goto start
:2
echo..X
goto start
:3
echo...X
goto start 
:4
echo....X
goto start
:5
echo.....X
goto start 
:6
echo......X
goto start
:7
echo.......X
goto start
:8
echo........X 
goto start
:9
echo.........X
goto start
```

I think (gathered from other people's posts), that the problem is either in the

```
set /a q="%z% %y% 1"
```

or

```
set y="-"
```

or

```
set y="+"
```

I know there are probably much easier ways to accomplish this, but this is how I learn.  The hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely a combination.

The syntax `set "var=string"` sets tha value of `var` to `string`, whereas `set var="string"` sets the value of `var` to `"string"`.

The first form is used to ensure that any trailing spaces on the line are **not** included the value assigned. The second includes quotes in the value assigned.

hence your `set /a q...` command would be resolved to

set /a q="5 "+" 1"

The solution is to use

```
set "y=+"
```

and

```
set /a q=%z% %y% 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it still is not working.  The same exact error is occurring.

Comment: Your next problem is that you are setting `x` to `%errorlevel%` which will therefore be 1 or 2. You are then testing against `a` and `d`, so both tests will fail. Batch simply continues to the next line and since `y` hasn't been established sees `set /a q=5  1` and reports operator missing. If you were to change `@echo off` to `echo on` (or simply `rem` it out) then you'd see the operation step-by-step. Once you've fixed that, you will have a problem with `q` being decremented from 1, as there is no test for `q==0` returning it to 9.

Comment: One little word of caution. You have a fail-to-fail scenario in your code that's best sorted now rather than later. There is a major difference between `&` and `&&`. `&` means 'do this, then do that'. `&&` means 'do this, and if it succeeds, do that'. The `set` will always succeed, so in this case, they are equivalent, but 'tis not always so. In nearly 20 years of writing batch with that syntax available, I've never yet used `&&` or `||` - mainly because I can't remember what the difference is.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know the difference between & ans &&.  script works now.  I didn't know I used ==a instead of ==1, so thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Magoo's answer - You have misunderstood `ErrorLevel` and `choice`

```
choice /c ad
set x=%errorlevel%
if %x%==a goto a
if %x%==d goto b
```

The `ErrorLevel` variable will only ever expand to a number. In the case of the `choice` command, it will expand to 1 through however many possible values you have provided. Expample

```
choice /c abc
```

If the user presses the `a` key, then `%errorlevel%` will expand to `1`. Whereas if they press `b`, it will expand to `2`, and so on.

So therefore both of your `if` checks are failing and you are going straight to `:sett`.

You should instead check if `%x%` equals `1` or `2`.

```
choice /c ad
set x=%errorlevel%
if %x%==1 goto a
if %x%==2 goto b
```

Comment: Oops!  I totally didn't catch that I wrote that.  Thank you very much!  BTW, I have never made that mistake before.

Answer (score 0):

a similar concept of doing the exact same thing ..... hope it helps ....
got this code some place else

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
title movement
color 0a
set length=
set height= a
:controls
cls
echo Use WASD to move your character ([]).
echo.
for %%a in ( %height% ) do echo.
echo %length%[]
choice /c wasd /n
if %errorlevel% equ 1 call:up
if %errorlevel% equ 2 call:left
if %errorlevel% equ 3 call:down
if %errorlevel% equ 4 call:right
:left
setlength=!length:~0,-1!
goto controls
:right
set length=%length%
goto controls
:up
set height=!height:~0,-2!
goto controls
:down
set height=%height% a
goto control
```