# how does this batch script works?

Tags: batch-file

i got this script for a site but i have some problems how the script works

the script

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
title movement
color 0a

set length=
set height=a

:controls
cls
echo Use WASD to move your character ([]).
echo.
for %%a in ( %height% ) do echo.
echo %length%[]
choice /c wasd /n
if %errorlevel% equ 1 call:up
if %errorlevel% equ 2 call:left
if %errorlevel% equ 3 call:down
if %errorlevel% equ 4 call:right

:left
set length=!length:~0,-1!
goto controls

:right
set length=%length%
goto controls

:up
set height=!height:~0,-2!
goto controls

:down
set height=%height% a
goto controls
```

ok now can someone explain the first line?
i serached the web and i think it will give value to variables when the command is reached

also i dont know what this means
set height=!height:~0,-2!
and this
set length=!length:~0,-1!

Comment: First things first, what is the task of the whole script?

Comment: I think, I have a Deja vue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23556986/2152082

Comment: the[] will move when you use wasd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `enabledelayedexpansion` see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx). (In short it makes variables work in a sane fashion.)

`enableextensions` seems to be a safety feature in case the command extensions have been disabled (though they appear to be on by default). It also isn't clear to me from a quick read what they are exactly (other than some newer command features).

Edit: Linked from the page @user3245060 mentions in hist comment is the [Cmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx) page which indicates (at least some) commands that are affected by `enableextensions` and indicates that further details may be available in those commands specific pages. (It would also seem that Noodles has some idea about what is involved here.)

`set height=!height:~0,-2!` appears to be string processing (as per [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#String_processing).

Comment: I will point out that I knew none of this before looking and do not do batch scripting at all. My point is that a few good minutes of searching could have found this all for you.

Comment: If running dos batch files it's best if extensions are off then commands follow Dos rules. It used to be important for compatability. Even though Dos batch are 99.9% compatible with extensions on.

Comment: tnx ok but still i have problem with enableextensions i dont know  what is do http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491001.aspx i road here about it still i confused

Comment: @user3245060 Edited to include a little bit more information.

Comment: `!height:~0,-2!` means "take all characters, starting with the first one (it starts at zero) until the last but two". Assigning this to `height` again results in stripping the last two characters from `height`

Comment: tnx i will try to find more info about this